# Defrag on SSD when DisableDeleteNotify

Tags: windows-10, ssd, defragment, trim

What does the scheduled defragmentation really do on a SSD when `DisableDeleteNotify` is manually set to `1` on recent Windows versions like Win 10?

Assuming that the SSD is properly detected by defragment as an SSD it is supposed it will go ahead to trim the free space; however configuring this parameter `DisableDeleteNotify` to `1` is globally documented in internet as fully disabling `trim` in Windows system-wide.

A link to any related documentation of MS would help to clarify the response.

The (off topic) context on this question is this: disabling instant trim while postponing it to a weekly task, similar to Linux, allows margin to forensic recover deleted data and files from SSD as it was possible with the old HDDs (now you only get zeroes).

Comment: Was there ever any hint from Microsoft that `it is supposed it will go ahead to trim the free space`?

Comment: Yes, here it mentions that SSDs are trimmed on scheduled defrag: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/defrag#scheduled-task

Comment: It's not *officially* documented to be `fully disabling trim in Windows`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-behavior Neither does its name hint so. Rather it pretty much implied that (only) notification (i.e. unmap/trim) upon (file) deletion will be disabled. Seems equivalent enough to the `nodiscard` mount option (which does not "block" `FITRIM` ioctl completely) in Linux to me.

Comment: I agree with your guess, however notice later down in your link it refers literally to the system-wide trimming: “To query the system to see if TRIM is enabled or not:” - and thus I wrote this question.

Comment: I'll say it's just a lazy way to put it. Wouldn't be surprised in the Microsoft universe. Either way, the best way to find the answer is to experiment yourself (with a "RZAT" drive and those little programs on github or so). I didn't read carefully enough to see if you can actually do something like `fstrim` though (i.e. without all the schedule crap).

Answer (score 0):

Please do not clean up the debris on the SSD, because that will reduce the lifespan of your SSD. To optimize the performance of SSD, please refer to [other methods](https://www.diskpart.com/ssd-management/ssd-defrag-0528.html).